# Simple way to check ldap (AD) is running

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm on centos, and I need to check that an AD server is running (is in another host). Which is the simplest way to check ldap (AD) is running? I have an application where I need to synchronize some users account with AD, but suddenly I'm getting 0 users found. I don't know much about AD and LDAP, I just tested with:

```
[root@mysystem]# ldapsearch -x
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Is that enough to check that LDAP is down? Or can it be another reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't contact LDAP server (-1) doesn't explicitly mean that your AD isn't "running". 
There are few things that could cause that error.

- **Server being shutdown**
- **Deamon stopped**
- and many more...

You might also have some misconfiguration, or something else blocking you to contact your AD.

However, if you can ldapsearch with some anonymous request (with -x) just before, I suppose that's an acceptable way to check.

If I refer myself to this previous post [How to test a LDAP connection from a client](https://serverfault.com/questions/452935/how-to-test-a-ldap-connection-from-a-client), the test you're currently using should be fine. (considering it was working before, and it's a connectivity issue, and not a misconfiguration)

Make yourself sure that anonymous authentication are enable, and you can actually query the AD with it.

[image]

Comment: I did `[root@mysystem]# telnet 10.0.0.230 389  Trying 10.0.0.230... Connected to 10.0.0.230. Escape character is '^]'.` so that means that the server is up but, then?

Comment: Can you maybe check the config files of the server/user trying to access your AD ? Check also if they can actually query with anonymous auth.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to ask to the sysadmin of the LDAP server I think :/ as I said I was able to connect to LDAP just a few days ago and suddenly it stopped

Comment: Ok, all was fine, connection was ok, LDAP is up. I had some issues in my app config. All good now.

Comment: Awesome ! Have a good day :D