# OpenLDAP authentication stopped working. Where to look for clues if ldapsearch works fine?

Tags: openldap, slapd

Authentication against an LDAP Server stopped on several  different web and workstation clients, for which i assume the host is at fault.

However `ldapsearch -x uid=user -LLL -H ldap://ldap.host.de -b dc=dep,dc=org,dc=de`(slightly redacted) provides a result as expected.
Using the `Fusiondirectory` to see and modify directories works fine as well..

The host runs `Debian 8`(i know) and `libldap 2.4.0`.
Method is self signed certificates, no kerberos or IPM.

`netstat -nat`shows `0.0.0.389 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN` and `0.0.0.636 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN`
`systemctl status slapd` shows `active(running)`

`/var/log/slapd.log` basically just shows slapd started at some time and did nothing? ever since.

The problem is really i'm kinda lost where to start looking at this point. As far i was concerned i always thought an working ldapsearch on a client was already the sign it being working correctly..

I know a familiar sounding question already exists, but doesn't give any clues to this one.
[How to test a LDAP connection from a client](https://serverfault.com/questions/452935/how-to-test-a-ldap-connection-from-a-client)

Edit: i found `ldapsearch -H ldap://ldap.host.de -x -b "" -s base -LLL supportedSASLMechanisms` to show:

```
supportedSASLMechanisms: GS2-IAKERB
supportedSASLMechanisms: GS2-KRB5
supportedSASLMechanisms: SCRAM-SHA-1
supportedSASLMechanisms: GSSAPI
supportedSASLMechanisms: GSS-SPNEGO
supportedSASLMechanisms: DIGEST-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: NTLM
supportedSASLMechanisms: CRAM-MD5
```

`cn=config.ldiff`:

```
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 a786a04b
dn: cn=config
objectClass: olcGlobal
cn: config
olcArgsFile: /var/run/slapd/slapd.args
olcPidFile: /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
olcToolThreads: 1
structuralObjectClass: olcGlobal
entryUUID: cc37ae96-2b8d-5484-8du2-997ff7483a4
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20151030091025Z
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/gov-chain.pem
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ldap.org.public.pem
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/private/ldap.org.private.pem
olcLogLevel: 64
olcLogFile: /var/log/slapd.log
entryCSN: 20151230114136.233704Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
modifyTimestamp: 20151230114136Z
```